# Excel Macros not working on shortcut key

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this one but can't seem to anything so hopefully someone here can help.

Every Macro I have runs fine via Macros, Run. BUT whenever I use a shortcut key (which never includes Shift, I've checked and know this causes problems) and varies between macros and workbooks (Ctrl+j, Ctrl+h, Ctrl+m)  if the macro includes an insert column code it fails and stalls at this point. Up to then its fine and, like I said, if I run it via Macro run, it works fine including this line. Any ideas? example of my insert column line of code as follows:

```
Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: Very weird...Or can you try with this statement and see if it will work?  `Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert`

Comment: Thanks - tried that and have exactly the same issue. works fine via run macro but fails with the shortcut. It is indeed, very weird.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Maybe try to run MS Office diagnostics and see if that will fix it for you automatically.  Other than that, I have no clue how to fix it.